# Why isn't \$I_s\$ (resultant current phasor) zero in FOC of PMSM?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

Suppose I have 3 phase (A,B,C) star connected PMSM.

For running this motor with FOC the \$I_s\$ (resultant current phasor or \$I_a+I_b+I_c\$, where \$I_i\$ is current in the phases) is keep at 90 degree with the rotor flux.

So, I can't understand why \$I_s\$ is not zero as \$I_a+I_b+I_c = 0 \$ according to Kirchhoff's current law.

How there is a non-zero \$I_s\$ which people are able to keep at 90 degrees?

Answer (score 0):

The sum of electrical current flowing through three wires is \$I_a+I_b+I_c = 0 \$, so still zero. I can't be otherwise, since as much current goes in one direction it has to return back in opposite direction, this is basic Kirchhoff law.

The \$I_s\$, stator current is the vector sum of all three currents, which are phase shifted by 120 degrees and also geometrically shifted by 120 degrees. What you get is a rotating stator current, search google about rotating magnetic field in the AC motor.